# this is regarding exponentials distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In an office building, the lift breaks down randomly at a mean rate of 3 times per week. The random variable X represents the time in days between successive lift breakdowns.

(i) Calculate the probability that the time interval between successive lift breakdowns is
between 2 and 3 days.

(ii) Find the probability that, after a breakdown has just occurred, at least 1 week will pass
without another breakdown occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time $X$ between breakdowns, measured in **days**, has mean $\frac{7}{3}$, so we are dealing with an exponential with parameter $3/7$, and hence density function $\frac{3}{7}e^{-3x/7}$, for $x\ge 0$.
We want the probability that $2\le X\le 3$. This probability is
$$\int_{2}^{3} \frac{3}{7}e^{-3x/7}\,dx.$$ 
Now it is just a matter of integrating.

The second question is in a sense simpler. We want the probability that $X\ge 7$. This is
$$\int_{7}^{\infty} \frac{3}{7}e^{-3x/7}\,dx.$$

**Remark:**   In some courses, for people with little knowledge of calculus, people are just *told* that if $X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, then $\Pr(X\le x)=F_X(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ (for $x\ge 0$).

In such a course, one would note that the probability that $X$ is between $a$ and $b$, where $0\le a\lt b$ is $F_X(b)-F_X(a)$. This is $(1-e^{-\lambda b})-(1-e^{-\lambda a})$, which simplifies to $e^{-\lambda a}-e^{-\lambda b}$.

Similarly, the probability that $X\gt a$ is $e^{-\lambda a}$.

Comment: *The time X between breakdowns, measured in days, is 7/3*... Actually 7/3 is the *mean* time and the time X itself is random.

Comment: @Did: Thanks, verbal slippage.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : sir if you can help me with this question also it will be so much useful in my exam which will held in next week
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401810/help-me-with-this-regarding-hypothesis-using-chi-square-distribution